# How to show fixed number of items of rows in a recyclerview

Tags: android

I'm trying to do menu footer which have 10 button and can horizontalscroll.

So i use recyclerview to do that.
What i want is this footer by default always show only first 5 items in screen with all screen size and user can scroll this.

So i have a question

1. How to show fixed number of items of rows in a recyclerview ?
2. How to set distance of 2 items in a list recyclerview ?

Thanks for read.

Comment: Just login to this account after a few years.
Here the solution.

1/ Suppose we want to fit 5 items in the screen, just set the width per items by parent width / 5

2/ uses a divider of recyclerView